# Longer hint in placeholder html

Tags: html, placeholder, hint

I need to write a longer hint in Placeholder html5.
But It's only allows My to write 15 16 character.
I tried  input type="text" placeholder="and here i need to write something a little bit longer but it just doesn't allow me"
I searched in Google but wasn't helpful.

Comment: Can you share an html example where you have this issue ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: <input type="text" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL" />

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to this code:

```
// HTML
<input placeholder="Please enter your name, address and shoe size">

// Javascript
input.setAttribute('size',input.getAttribute('placeholder').length);
```

I got the answer from this link [How to set an input width to match the placeholder text width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302794/how-to-set-an-input-width-to-match-the-placeholder-text-width), if you want the details you can check the link, thank you